# Как програмно установить zoom в браузере?

Tags: javascript

Как програмно емулировать нажатие ctl(command)+ или ctl(command) - тоесть увеличение маштаба програмно при условии в js ?

Comment: пихнуть `body` `transform: scale`, но это лишь эмуляция, до браузера вам не достучаться в целях безопасности